# Habilitar/Desabilitar GPS via Delphi

Tags: android, delphi-xe5, gps

Há algum código especifico para habilitar o GPS, mas ainda não encontrei.

O que vi online foi:

> [Post na Stack - On/Off GPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528984/android-device-gps-on-off-programatically/22529084#22529084)

porém, este codigo é em JAVA.

O que conseguir montar em Delphi foi:

```
var
  poke : JIntent;
begin
  poke.setClassName(StringToJString('com.android.settings'),StringToJString('com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider'));
  poke.addCategory(StringToJString('android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE'));
  poke.setData(TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(StringToJString('3')));
  SharedActivity.sendBroadcast(poke);
end;
```

Segundo código que consegui para ativar é:

```
TJSettings_Secure.JavaClass.putString(SharedActivityContext.getContentResolver,
                                      TJSettings_Secure.JavaClass.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED,
                                      TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Terceiro foi:

```
TJSettings_Secure.JavaClass.setLocationProviderEnabled(
  SharedActivityContext.getContentResolver,
  TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER, 
  true);
```

O quarto foi:

```
Intent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER);
  intent.putExtra(StringToJString('enabled'), true);
  SharedActivity.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Todos eles necessitam, aparentemente de permissão para habilitar e lidar diretamente com os settings do android.

O erro que obtive foi(em todos):

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to secure settings requires android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
```

Nas minhas opções, estão habilitadas as permissões normalmente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sem falar que também tentei colocar as permissões diretamente no Manifest do Android.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
```

Alguém tem alguma dica para me dar?

Comment: Ramon, você não teria que usar um `JString` dentro do `setClassName`?

Comment: Wakim, segue o post completo. Por favor da uma olhadinha :D

Comment: Ramon, essa permissão é apenas para apps de sistema ou firmware, terá que ver outra forma. Nunca usei o Delphi pra desenvolver para Android, vou tentar pesquisar algo pra ver se ajuda.

Comment: nao tem como alterar via código o firmware? de acordo com minha pesquisa, era para ter funcionado a partir do momento que setei true no WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS.

Comment: Não não, esse código até funciona, mas só apps que pertencem ao sistema ou são apps de firmware (feitos pelos fabricantes do dispositivo) podem ter essa `permission` (`WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS`). Eu tenho um app que habilita e desabilita o `GPS`, logo deve haver alguma outra forma.

Comment: Mas seu app é em Delphi ou em Java?

Comment: Ter um app é ter baixado na Google Play. O app é o `Extended Settings`. Ele habilita e desabilita o gps. Logo deve ter uma alternativa.

Comment: Com certeza, deve haver, eu devo estar fazendo é a pergunta errada.

Comment: Espera mais um pouco, alguém deve saber como fazer isso.

Comment: pelo que pesquisei, não há solução para ativar/desativar o GPS programaticamente, é uma falha de segurança (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35924) que foi corrigida na versão 4.4 apenas, porém existe um código que pode vir a funcionar (não tenho certeza) com API menor que o 4.4. O App que falei (`Settings Extended`) me redireciona para a configuração de `Location` nas configurações do dispositivo. Fiz esse Gist para os dois exemplos: https://gist.github.com/wakim/3cf3c31ed39048bd7b50. Estão em Java, mas pode tentar converter para Delphi.

Comment: Mais alguém, tem alguma dica para dar?

Answer (score 3):

Sei que a dúvida é antiga mas como passei trabalho com isso também, segue uma solução. Uso Delphi XE7. Basicamente quando clico no botão ele abre a tela para habilitar o GPS do Android.

```
Uses
Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  Androidapi.JNI.Location,
  Androidapi.JNIBridge,
  Androidapi.JNI.Os,
  Androidapi.Helpers,
  Androidapi.JNI.Provider;
.............................
procedure TForm2.Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Provider:string;
  Settings_secure:TJSettings_Secure;
  Intent:JIntent;
begin
  Provider:=JStringToString(Settings_secure.JavaClass.getString(
  SharedActivityContext.getContentResolver,
  TJSettings_system.javaClass.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED));
// if pos(‘gps‘,provider)=0 then
// begin
    Intent:=TJIntent.Create;
    Intent.setAction(TJSettings.javaClass.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
// end;
end;
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao SOpt @Evandro! Seria bem legal se você adicionasse comentários no seu código explicando o funcionamento, ajudaria bastante quem for implementar seu código :DD

Comment: Caramba cara! Muito obrigado, a eras tento fazer isto! Agora, so uma perguntinha @Evandro, esta solução funcionaria no XE5?

Comment: Ramon, a referencia que busquei foi em um desenvolvedor coreano que na época utilizava o XE5.